# Add content editor webpart programmatically and still keep it editable

Tags: content-editor-web-part

Essentially what I want is to pre-load the existing content editor with some text may be from a configuration(by adminstrator) or from the list. 
So I am creating a custom wp that will act like a wrapper to the existing content editor and add some text to it. But this makes the CEWP uneditable to the user. Please suggest.
I am using SharePoint 2010 foundation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my working code for SP 2010 for adding text to the existing CEWP. I think it must be identical to the example mentioned above:

```
SPListItem pageItem;// Need to get page SPListItem
SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = SPContext.Current.Web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageItem.Url, PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            ContentEditorWebPart contentEditor = manager.WebParts.OfType<ContentEditorWebPart>().Single(); // You can choose a specific CEWP instance by any conditions if you like
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            var contentRoot = xDoc.CreateElement("ContentRoot");
            string content = "abcde!";
            contentRoot.InnerText = editor.Content;
            contentEditor.Content = contentRoot;
            manager.SaveChanges(contentEditor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the webpart with custom code shouldn't be needed; should be able to do what you want by updating the contents.  The following article should get you moving in the right direction.

[Programmatically Updating a SharePoint Content Editor Web Part](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2009/02/i-found-to-be-bit-tricky-to-update.html) -- note this is for SharePoint 2007, but as you didn't mention what version you are using...

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010 foundation.

Comment: It is a great solution but what if I had more than one content editor on the page? I am looking more towards setting (preloading) text to a specific CEWP on the page and still keep it editable for the user.